# How to install budgie desktop on elementary OS (Loki)?

Tags: release-loki, ubuntu

To install this I used an Ubuntu guide: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/09/install-budgie-desktop-on-ubuntu
but it doesn't work as expected.

It doesn't show a `unity-greeter` session menu like described in the article. What did I do wrong, or rather what went wrong and how can I rectify this issue?

Comment: The way I see it, Elementary IS Pantheon and it's design language. Without Pantheon, it's really just Ubuntu. So if you wanted to run Budgie, why not just install Ubuntu Budgie? Or even better, Solus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing went wrong and you didn't do anything wrong (except ask on the wrong stack exchange site and use poor formatting, but I fixed that for you :).

What happened is that elementary uses a different greeter-session than Ubuntu (`pantheon-greeter` as opposed to `unity-greeter`).

You just need to chose your desktop environment before you login. You can do this no matter which greeter-session your system uses.

Answer (score 0):

A word of warning, Budgie and Pantheon don't play nice.

I installed Budgie desktop the same way as you did, on EOS Loki, and it was great, I loved it, but when I signed into pantheon things got screwy. I couldn't open pantheon-files, there was no wifi connectivity, the themes and icons changed and I couldn't change them back. And when I tried to shut down it wouldn't.

Maybe it's my machine, or one of my applications, I don't know. If you have similar problems there is a method to remove Budgie detailed at the end of this page: [install-budgie-desktop-ubuntu-16-04-lts](https://www.ostechnix.com/install-budgie-desktop-ubuntu-16-04-lts/).