# Can I safely install a bare bone Unity Shell in elementaryOS 0.4?

Tags: release-loki

I will be removing Ubuntu from my system but I would like to keep Unity shell in my system. As the other distro I use is a Arch distro so Unity can't be installed there. So can I install a bare bones Unity 7 shell in my elementary OS 0.4 ????

Comment: If you want to use Unity you might want to reconsider removing elementary OS and keeping Ubuntu instead.

Answer (score 4):

Installing another desktop environment on elementary OS will probably break things. The elementary apps are designed for GTK+ and Granite, and they may not work properly under Unity. Additionally, I don't believe that Pantheon Greeter provides a way to choose your desktop environment at login. [Edit] I may be wrong about that last part - see the comment below!

See also: [this comment on installing the Budgie DE](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/10339/792).

If you'd still like to proceed, I'd recommend setting up elementary on a virtual machine and trying to set up Unity there before trying this on your primary OS.

Comment: I would like to make a argument that LightDM allows choosing of session during login and Pantheon Greeter also does. I can say it because the Ubuntu 16.10 installation that I will be removing has Unity, Cinnamon and Pantheon installed with Pantheon Greeter being the default for LightDM.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the heads-up! How does one choose a DE from Pantheon Greeter?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the terminal emulator? if so ubuntu use's gnome-terminal? or do you mean install a just ubuntu system with no xserver? "Unity" is the desktop flavor along with the display manager that it comes with im not sure what a unity shell is.